# How to format output in a textfield in Java?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I append text to the textfield. Since some states have long names, the columns are not
nicely formatted. What can I do?

```
...
_result.append(text+"\n");
```

It looks like:

```
Alabama       1900       Birmingham       Wide-Awake       1
District of Columbia       1901       Birmingham       Wide-Awake       40
Illinois       1900       Blakeley       Blakeley Sun       10
Colorado       1901       Blakeley       Blakeley Sun       20
West Virginia       1900       Cahawba       Alabama Watchman       30
Alabama       1901       Cahawba       Alabama Watchman       50
```

Comment: Add spaces after the name so that each string ends up the same length though some have less or more spaces after the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Formatter Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to format the string in a given format. This allows you to specify format specifiers through which you can set the width of each parameter. By doing this you can have the columns align correctly.

```
String[][] stateInfo = new String[][]{
                        {"Alabama", "1900", "Birmingham", "Wide-Awake", "1"},
                        {"Illinois", "1900", "Blakeley", "Blakeley Sun", "10"}};
for (String[] si: stateInfo){
    String s = String.format("%1$-12s %2$-5s %3$-12s %4$-12s %5$-2s ",
                                    si[0],si[1],si[2],si[3],si[4]);
    System.out.println("String:"+s);
}
```

In the format %1s:

> 's', 'S' = If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". If arg implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking 
>   arg.toString().
>
> "-" = The result will be left-justified.

Please refer to the documentation in [Formatter Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for other formats supported.

Comment: Thank You. That works excellent. Could you please explain the `-12s`, `-5s` tokens, I am not sure about the logic of this regex. Thank You

Comment: Does this "s" in `-12s` refer to the `String s`?

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA "s" stands for type "general" which in this case is String. I've updated the answer with additional details.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add tab(s) depending the longest string in the columns. Something like this:

```
// add a tab(s) after each column value
_result.append(columnFiled +"\t");

//Finally add a new line
_result.append("\n");
```